# Pods: Authors to Custom Field

Tags: pods-framework

I have 200 blog articles linked to different users. Now I moved them to new Pods custom field "author" because I don't want different user that could access to my blog.

The problem is that I have to link every post to different "author" custom field. Is it possible doing this operation in bulk mode or i have to edit every single article?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I've created this script:

```
<?php
  global $wpdb;
  $postwp = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT ID,post_author,post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_type = 'post'" );
  $users = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT post_id,meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'id_utente_user'" );

  foreach($postwp as $key1=>$value1)
  {
    foreach($users as $key2=>$value2)
    {
       if($value1->post_author==$value2->meta_value)
       {
           add_post_meta( $value1->ID, 'autore', $value2->post_id );
       }
   }
  }
  ?>
```

I hope It could be useful.